# How do you find most duplicates in a 2d list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, 2d

I have a 2d list that i would like to return the most duplicates by using a list comprehension. For example, i have a list below

```
a = [[10, 15, 17,],[20,21,27],[10,15,17],[21,27,28],[21,27,28],[5,10,15],[15,17,20]]
```

I would like my result to be

```
b = [[10,15,17],[21,27,28]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line splitted here:

```
[ a[k] 
  for k in range(len(a)) 
  if  a.count( a[k] ) > 1
  and k == a.index( a[k] ) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The common solution for counting repetitions is [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [[10, 15, 17], [20, 21, 27], [10, 15, 17], [21, 27, 28], [21, 27, 28], [5, 10, 15], [15, 17, 20]]

# count duplicates
counts = Counter(map(tuple, a))

# find the maximum count (the values of counts are the duplicate count)
maximum_count = max(counts.values())

# filter and convert back to list
result = [list(e) for e, count in counts.items() if count == maximum_count]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[10, 15, 17], [21, 27, 28]]
```

In your case in particular as the elements of the list are list, you need to convert them to tuples (to make them hashable), then just filter the list and keep the elements with maximum count.

Comment: Instead of using `max(counts.values())
` you could use `counts.most_common(1)[0][1]`

Comment: @Jab according to the documentation the way to go is max(counts.values()), most_common uses a heap. You can find the details here https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest, in the paragraph below.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this to find the count for each element, and store the maximum count. Then, display all elements that have the maximum count (removing duplicates).

The below code will work for you:

```
a = [[10, 15, 17,],[20,21,27],[10,15,17],[21,27,28],[21,27,28],[5,10,15],[15,17,20]]
check=0
for i in a:
    if a.count(i) > check:
         check=a.count(i)    #Check to see maximum count

b=[]
for i in a:
    if a.count(i) == check:   #Choosing elements with maximum count
        if i not in b:        #Eliminating duplicates
            b.append(i)

print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[[10, 15, 17], [21, 27, 28]]
```